# Cannot boot from live USB used for installation when I want to re-install 18.04.1

Tags: boot, usb, 18.04, reinstall

What would make re-install hang while it installed 18.04.1 easily the first time a week ago?

I decided to re-install, this time with whole disk encryption, and start fresh.

I inserted the USB stick, re-booted, and the system hung up with a blank black screen with a solid, unblinking cursor. The hard drive appeared to be spinning hard. Nothing else happened, the drive just spun and the blank, solid cursor stayed in place. I left it for five minutes, then tried again, leaving it for 10 minutes, and saw no changes. I checked the BIOS boot order and it was on the USB stick. On the first installation it wasn't instantaneous, but it loaded and gave me a screen within a minute as best as I can recall. This time not.

I checked the Wiki for re-installation - it pointed me towards something called UbuntuInstaller, which my command line doesn't recognize. If I need to add the USB to Network settings I could use advice on that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of USB are you using? A standard live ISO?

Comment: Desktop ISO. Generic USB - doesn't even say if it's USB3, so I suspect it's 2.0. I think the USB might be a problem; I'll get some new USB3 sticks, then try again. I've tried this one several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the boot order step, the USB was listed twice. I should have chosen the one without the "EFI" at the end. It works fine now.